# Bridging Ajaxplorer with Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, bridge, pydio

I have downloaded the latest releases of Joomla (3.0.2) and Ajaxplorer (4.2.3).
I am trying to bridge the two for authentication purposes and have run into a snag. The current auth bridge is for Joomla 1.6... So I went ahead and figured I would give it a shot. The normal way to implement the bridge was just fine except for two things.

1. The "DS" in the /joomla/plugins/user/ajaxplorer/ajaxplorer.php line 14 needed ' around it...still not sure why but it got rid of the errors so I'm hoping that I'm safe in assuming that it's no longer going to cause a problem.
   Originally it looked like this:

> require_once ( JPATH_ROOT .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'html'.DS.'parameter.php' );

But after getting the errors I changed it to:

> require_once ( JPATH_ROOT .'DS'.'libraries'.'DS'.'joomla'.'DS'.'html'.'DS'.'parameter.php' );

All I did was add ' around the DS. Got rid of the errors.

1. The same file from above is calling for a file called parameter.php that doesn't exist. I have manually looked for the file but didn't find it in that directory or in any other directory. Here is the actual error that I got when trying to login or do anything with authentication.

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\joomlaDSlibrariesDSjoomlaDShtmlDSparameter.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\plugins\user\ajaxplorer\ajaxplorer.php on line 14

Don't worry, this is only a test server, the file path is not the same as the one that would be published.

So the question is: Does anyone know what was in parameter.php or know what joomla used instead of parameter.php that I could point ajaxplorer.php to? I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You actually have to problems:

**First**, from what I can see you've used DS in Joomla! 3.0

DS has been deprecated in 2.5 and [removed in 3.0](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#General_changes). Regardless of a sever on *unix or Windows, you can just use `/`.

So it should look like this (which does not work anyway):

`require_once JPATH_ROOT . '/libraries/joomla/html/parameter.php';`

**Second**, JParameter (which was inside parameter.php) [has been removed.](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#Removed_classes) Suggested replacement is JForm or JRegistry.

I can't tell you how you can fix this, because I haven't worked yet with ajaxplorer. It's just clear that you need to digg a bit inside the plugin to make it work.

Also be aware that **Joomla! 3.0** is a short time support release. Soon it will be 3.1 etc.. till 3.5 which will be the LTS.

**I would suggest that you have a look at Joomla! 2.5** which is already supported by ajaxplorer.

Comment: Thanks Valentin. I downloaded 2.5 and have been poking around in parameter.php. I am not the best with PHP so I will collaborate with some of my friends to see if we can solve this issue. Until then, I'll take your advice and downgrade until a solution to this problem is found. Thanks for the reply.